# React: Prevent auto-refresh when a class's state change

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.

I have a class-based component. Let's say the code inside is:

```
state = {message: "Hello"}

render(){
<div>  
   <p>this.state.message</p>
   <button onclick={() =>this.setState({message: "World"})}>click here</button>
</div>
}
```

When I click the button, display on the screen change from "Hello" to "World", but then the page refresh and the display turns back to the default "Hello" again.

How should I prevent the automatic refresh? I want my page to display "World" after I press the button.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), better don't ask "what might be the reason" and reproduce with minimal code that causes the undesired behaviour.

Comment: If the button is rendered at all within a `form` element then by default (`type="submit"`) it will submit the form when clicked. More context is necessary here.

Comment: this code you provided  works fine without being refreshed.   please share  your main code, so we can trace whats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `button type` to the control, as by default this is set to `submit`, which causes the page to refresh.

```
<button type="button" onclick={() =>this.setState({message: "World"})}>click here</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Answer (score 1):

A `<button>` element's default behavior is to submit the page (or form that it's in), which triggers a refresh.

To avoid this, set its type to `button`:

```
<button type="button" onclick={() =>this.setState({message: "World"})}>click here</button>
```